# How do I copy 24bpp data from a buffer into an existing cv::Mat?

Tags: opencv

I have an existing pre-allocated CV_8UC3 cv::Mat, and I would like to copy 24bpp (strided RGB) data from a buffer into the Mat's data buffer. Is there a routine for achieving this?

note: I am familiar with the constructor route for achieving this, but I do not want to create a new cv::Mat.

Comment: Are the Mat step and the buffer stride equal?